# Failed to communicate with the mailbox database

Tags: exchange-2013

I have a single exchange server 2013 standard. Exchange and it's database are installed on a single partition (i have 2 partitions, the other one is system).

I have been doing multiple imports via new-import request, and today i ran out of space on the database partition. i have increased partition size, but started getting "Failed to communicate with the mailbox database" error when i try to do anything with imports, exports, and a few other commands.

I was unable to stop, remove or view statistics on import requests. i dismounted the database, and that allowed me to remove all requests, but i am still unable to do anything regarding imports and exports.

Here is an example:
[PS] C:\Windows\system32>New-MailboxImportRequest -Mailbox vsmaj -FilePath \206.156.102.185\mail\VSMAJLAG.PST -v

VERBOSE: [20:59:37.673 GMT] New-MailboxImportRequest : Active Directory session settings for 'New-MailboxImportRequest' are: View Entire Forest: 'False', Default Scope: 'excel-assemblies.com', Configuration Domain Controller: 'WIN2012DC.excel-assemblies.com', Preferred Global Catalog: 'WIN2012DC.excel-assemblies.com', Preferred Domain Controllers: '{ WIN2012DC.excel-assemblies.com }'

VERBOSE: [20:59:37.767 GMT] New-MailboxImportRequest : Runspace context: Executing user: excel-assemblies.com/Users/Administrator, Executing user organization: , Current organization: , RBAC-enabled: Enabled.

VERBOSE: [20:59:37.767 GMT] New-MailboxImportRequest : Beginning processing

VERBOSE: [20:59:37.782 GMT] New-MailboxImportRequest : Instantiating handler with index 0 for cmdlet extension agent "Admin Audit Log Agent".

VERBOSE: [20:59:37.782 GMT] New-MailboxImportRequest : Current ScopeSet is: { Recipient Read Scope: {{, }}, Recipient Write Scopes: {{, }}, Configuration Read Scope: {{, }}, Configuration Write Scope(s): {{, }, }, Exclusive Recipient Scope(s): {}, Exclusive Configuration Scope(s): {} }

VERBOSE: [20:59:37.782 GMT] New-MailboxImportRequest : The current object has been processed by the cmdlet extension agent with index 0.

VERBOSE: [20:59:37.782 GMT] New-MailboxImportRequest : Searching objects "vsmaj" of type "ADUser" under the root "$null".

VERBOSE: [20:59:37.860 GMT] New-MailboxImportRequest : Previous operation run on domain controller 'WIN2012DC.excel-assemblies.com'.

VERBOSE: [20:59:37.860 GMT] New-MailboxImportRequest : Searching objects "Mailbox Database 0886186604" of type "MailboxDatabase" under the root "$null".

VERBOSE: [20:59:37.860 GMT] New-MailboxImportRequest : Previous operation run on domain controller 'WIN2012DC.excel-assemblies.com'.

VERBOSE: [20:59:37.954 GMT] New-MailboxImportRequest : Admin Audit Log: Entered Handler:OnComplete.

THIS PART IS RED

Failed to communicate with the mailbox database.

- CategoryInfo: ResourceUnavailable: (:) [New-MailboxImportRequest], StorageTransientException
- FullyQualifiedErrorId: 6CBA0560,Microsoft.Exchange.Management.RecipientTasks.NewMailboxImportRequest
- PSComputerName: mail.excel-assemblies.com

UP TO HERE

VERBOSE: [20:59:37.954 GMT] New-MailboxImportRequest : Ending processing 
[PS] C:\Windows\system32>

Anyone have any ideas what to do?

Comment: are you missing a "\" in front of the filepath for the PST?  Also, you might want to move the file to a local store and try it.  I know that doesn't address the mailbox database communications issue, but it might be referring to the source and not the destination.

Comment: the command is fine, it just lost one \ during formatting. If i click on edit i can see it, so i guess it's a html problem. It's the same command i used to import before i ran out of space. tried it on a local file as well but same thing :(currently have 40GB of free space on the server.

Comment: do you have more than one database?  If so are you able to do mailbox moves between databases?  Maybe your database file is corrupted somehow?  Try creating a new mail database and see if it will import into the 2nd database

Comment: Move mailbox to another database appears to work. Also if i create a new user in the old database i can't import into it. If i create it in a new database import works. I'm guessing i have a problem with the database. Is there any way to clean, or completely move the database to a new file? and would that take long(i have 500gb of emails in it).

Comment: In your case if it was me, I'd make a new database and move everyone over.  In fact, I would split all that mail into much smaller databases and not put all your eggs in one basket.  In my case, I have about 900GB of email for ~150 mailboxes.  We have 7 mail databases and 7 archive databases.  I try to keep the active mail databases around the 30GB mark and that seems to limit my exposure.  Just food for thought.  But I'd agree, I think your mail database is hosed.

Comment: Also my database maintanence time started an hour ago. Is there a possibility that that might fix it? In that case i'll leave everything and check back in a few hours.

Comment: If the database is corrupt, not likely, but I don't actually know for sure.  If you know it is corrupt, I wouldn't leave the mail in there at all.  With the amount of mail you are talking about, moving it will take a while...

Comment: Well, the mail database is supposed to be arround 100 gb once everything is done, but i first need to import about 1tb of emails from the old servers(migrating from an old lotus notes and need to get all mails into pst files since i don't have anything else that can read lotus files)... That's also why i ran out of space. It was never supposed to be that many. As far as migration goes, can i move all mailboxes and remove the old database? Or does it still contain system files and whatnot? Also will the old db shrink as files get moved?

Comment: The old file will not shrink by itself, which can present a problem if you are short on space.  But if you are importing 1TB of data in, you need to likely do a bit more prep so there is plenty of space.  If your version of Exchange allows for Archiving, it might be worth your time to look into it.  You can import mail into the archive directly for the user once the mailbox archive is created.  This is helpful in instances like this where you'll be dumping huge chunks of mail into the database(s).  Just something to think about.

Comment: Unfortunately i don't have enterprise cals so i can't use archiving the normal way. i'll just dump a 2tb hdd in there to do the switching arround. Can you do a normal answer so i can mark it?

Comment: done... With that amount of old mail, it is well worth the expense of the Enterprise CALs for Archiving.  It has been a huge lifesaver for us.  Active mailboxes are about 175GB of our ~900GB storage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed in the comments section (and I shouldn't have done that), your problem is likely due to a corrupt mail database file in Exchange.  In practice, limiting the size of the database files limits the number of mailboxes effected when one of the database files gets corrupted.  In your case it was due to a lack of available drive space during a New-MailboxImportRequest.